# How do I compare whether same/intersection data is there in one and another row in same table when I have huge data in the table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the sample data below. Now, I just want to compare one record with all other records in the same table and we have to give ID if that record colloids with any other records in the remaining records. And column is with comma separated data, So if we have 'A,C' as Name in one record and 'A' in another record(Check the input from text) then it colloid each other because 'A' is common in both.
In the same way one of the record is not having anything in the Name it is NULL. When it is Null it should colloid with remaining other records. Like this Name column I have around 10 columns to verify data.

**Input**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,C |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | NULL |

**OUTPUT**

| ID | ColloidID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |

Problem : I have implemented solution like below, and it working fine as expected. But the thing here is it is fine when less data in the table(<100k) but it's taking more time and space when dealing with millions of data(Ex : >20M Data)

```
 SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,B.ID AS ColloidID
 FROM #Temp1 A
 CROSS APPLY #Temp1 B
 WHERE A.ID<>B.ID
 AND master.dbo.fIntersection(COALESCE(A.Name,B.Name,''),COALESCE(B.Name,A.Name,'')) = 1
```

Comment: *"I have a table with the given data in the image."* There is no image in your question, however, please see the FAQ: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What is `fIntersection`? That isn't a built-in function and having a user-defined function in `master` feels like a poor choice of location. User Defined scalar functions have a reputation for performing poorly (unless you're using SQL Server 2019 and it's inlinable). Using functions on a column in the `WHERE` normally makes the query non-SARGable as well, which *will* (significantly) affect performance.

Comment: `huge Millions of data(Ex : >20M Data)` that's not huge. Querying 20M records won't be slow if the tables have proper indexes and the query doesn't have performance problems. Storing a custom function in *master* though, is a big problem in itself. Using a function to compare properties will force a 20M by 20M comparison and thus is **very** bad. `WHERE A.Name=B.Name or (a.Name is null and b.name is null)` will be very fast if `Name` is indexed in both tables

Comment: Now, I have added link to check the image. Anyway it's table with dummy data. And I used fIntersection user defined function because I have to check intersection of data in between the records for all the columns for that I need to use STRINT_SPLIT for multiple times. So, in a simple way I have created user-defined function with 2 in params. Then it will check whether 2 params intersected or not in the function and it will give boolean value. Ex : If 'A,C' and 'A' then A is intersected it will give 1.

Comment: Don't post images. Images can't be copied, tested or executed. What you describe isn't "simple", it's several serious performance problems. Any one of them would prevent the database from using any indexes. Storing a comma-separated string instead of using multiple rows is a *major* design bug.

Comment: I repeat. 20M isn't huge. It's not even a lot these days. Using comma separated values instead of a many-to-many table though, would cause serious problems even with a 10K-row table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you please check the image once, It won't work with equalization of names. Because one record is 'A,C' and one is 'A' and these are colloiding how we get record in select list if we use direct equalization

Comment: Again: no-one wants to see images, we can't copy it or do anything with it. We need the sample data as *text*. Also I don't understand the logic of the null row.

Comment: @Charlieface the logic for null is, As it is having no data then it is eligible to colloid with remaining all other records.

Comment: Those all other records are 20M-1. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not store multiple pieces of info in a single column.

Be that as it may, you can use a nested `EXISTS` with `STRING_SPLIT` to compare the two columns.

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM #Temp1 t1
JOIN #Temp1 t2 ON t2.ID <> t1.ID
  AND (t1.Name IS NULL OR t2.Name IS NULL
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(t1.Name, ',') s1
      JOIN STRING_SPLIT(t2.Name, ',') s2 ON s2.value = s1.value
    )
  )
ORDER BY
  t1.ID,
  t2.ID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/1AanbXby)

Comment: This will be extremely slow. That's N^2, ie 4*10^14 comparisons.

Comment: True, but not sure what other option there is given the data structure and desired results.

Comment: The only realistic option is to normalize the data. Inserting the normalized data into a new indexed table and then querying will be faster than performing all those comparisons.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Even though after doing normalized data into a new indexed table and then querying is not showing much effect. Till now almost 3 hrs completed but still query in execution.

Comment: @ABC the query you wrote is extremely slow and hardly makes sense - it generates *billions* of rows. Treating `NULL` as a wildcard will generate 40M rows for each null (each combination appears twice in reversed order). If you write a query that returns billions of rows, performance will be slow no matter what. What are you going to do with those billions of results anyway?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos out of all the records I have to show the list of ID's which are colloids each other.

Comment: Can any one suggest me any other ways to avoid this performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

20M isn't a lot of data, provided a good database design is used, with proper indexes. This is definitely not a good design. It violates the most basic design rule - one value per field. As a result, it's impossible to index `Name`, forcing 4*10^14 comparisons.

The only way to get acceptable performance is to fix the design. To do that `Name` has to be split into separate rows. The data needs to be stored in a table whose `Name` column is covered by an index or primary key:

```
create table #Id_Names (
    ID bigint not null,
    Name varchar(30)  null,
    INDEX IX_Id_Names (Name,ID)
);
GO
INSERT INTO #Id_Names (Id,Name)
select ID,value
from #Temp1 t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Name,',');
```

After that, the query is simplified to :

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID,t2.ID as ColloidID
FROM #Id_Names  t1 
    INNER JOIN #Id_Names t2
ON t1.ID<>t2.ID 
    AND (t1.Name=t2.Name 
         OR t1.Name IS NULL
         OR t2.Name IS NULL)
```

This can run a *lot* faster. The only real problem is the logic of treating `NULL` as a wildcard. This will return the entire table. And since the table joins itself, each null will result in (20M-1)^2 extra rows. The same relations will be repeated twice, eg `(1,4)` and `(4,1)`

If `#Temp1` was a proper table, an alternative would be to create an indexed view. Creating an index over a VIEW essentially generates, stores *and* updates its results automatically.

Another option is to create a [Clustered Columnstore index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16). This provides both compression *and* acceleration. The data is stored per column in buckets of roughly 1M rows. In each bucket, each column value is only stored once.

```
create table #Id_Names (
    ID bigint not null,
    Name varchar(30) null,
    INDEX CCI_Id_Names CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
);
```

Comment: Still needs (20m * NumOfNames) ^ 2 comparisons, which might be pretty big also. I agree that this design is much better though

Comment: Not if the server can process ordered rows. In that case it can scan forward and compare the data from each side. If this was an equijoin only 20M comparisons would be needed. Far less buffering would be needed too. A lot depends on the actual values. If `Name` has high cardinality (ie lots of different values), that order can be used. The `t1.ID!=t2.ID` can cause problems, but SQL Server can probably use bitmap operations to handle this.

Comment: @Charlieface more importantly though, without normalized data there's no way to improve performance.

Comment: The `OR` is most concerning, and will probably prevent an equijoin on `Name`